# KeyCloak: Deploy Custom Theme in Docker

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, keycloak

I know how to deploy custom KeyCloak theme in Windows using both ways as stated [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes):

1. Copy-paste theme in **themes** directory
2. Using archive deploy

Can someone please suggest how to do this in **docker**?

Comment: What have you tried? You can map host directories for the container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, did the following way. Copy the customized theme named **MyTheme** at some path say "/root/" from **windows** to the **linux** server using **FileZilla** or similar tools.

To list all the docker instances that are running on the server, use the following command:

> docker ps

Find the container in which keycloak is running and pick its container id.

Now use the following command to copy the custom theme in the **themes** folder.:

> docker cp /root/MyTheme/.
>   your_keycloak_container_id:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/MyTheme

Restart server.

Comment: Thanks for true reply. For 18.0.2 /opt/keycloak/themes/MyTheme now.

Comment: @withoutOne for keycloak 18.0.2 it is still opt/jboss/keycloak/themes. I think it starts to change with 19+.

Answer (score 22):

This is what I did:

1. Created Dockerfile like below

   > ```
   > FROM jboss/keycloak
   >
   > COPY ./themes/<yourThemeName>/ /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/<yourThemeName>/
   > ```
2. Built new docker image from this file

   > `docker build -t <yourDockerHubUserName>/keycloak .`
3. Run this docker image

   > `docker container run --name <someContainerName> -p 8080:8080 -e
   >   KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password
   >   <yourDockerHubUserName>/keycloak`
4. Check if new theme shows up by logging into admin console at 
   http://localhost:8080/auth and go to realms/themes click drop down list of themes and you should see `<yourThemeName>`

Comment: Did it work using additional configuration? I tried, without success using this keycloak image: `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest` .

Comment: For keycloak 19.x , (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest)

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/keycloak/themes/<yourThemeName>/login

COPY ./themes/<yourThemeName>/login  /opt/keycloak/themes/<yourThemeName>/login

```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is by far to bundle the theme into a `.jar` file and drop it here: `/opt/keycloak/providers`.
[Here](https://github.com/micedre/keycloak-mail-whitelisting) you have a plugin that implement this approach.
You can also use [keycloakify](https://github.com/InseeFrLab/keycloakify), it bundles the theme for you.

Comment: Keycloakify is only valid for keycloak v11+. What about cases of keycloak version under 11.

Comment: Is it though? I am the author of Keycloakify and I made 11+ because when I started developping Keycloakify it was the current version but it's probably retro compatible.

Comment: on keycloak 20 docker container i had to put it inside /opt/keycloak/providers to make it work

Comment: I can not find folder called keycloak inside /opt